# How to fix Unhandled exception issue when importing CSV into mySQL (CSV file contains Chinese character)

Tags: mysql, csv

Hi I would like to import csv(contain chinese character) into mySQL, but It seemed to have error.
"Unhandled exception: 'charmap' ........", some of comments suggests to change the encoding to UTF8 but after I changed, the problem still exists. So here is my question

- If the problem is about encoding, how can I change encoding using excel if the row is more than 2milions.
- If the problem is not about encoding, how to solve this problem.[image]

Comment: Do not use workbench, use command-line client with proper LOAD DATA and correct data CHARACTER SET specification. Check also charset settings for table columns and client connection.

Comment: Depending on your source, Chinese text files are often encoded in GB18030 (`Guójiā Biāozhǔn (国家标准)`, for National Standard 18030.  Try to select that in your input.